# Bought in, bought on, bought from, bought at?

Tags: prepositions

I bought this bike *in|on|from|at* an online store.

I bought this bike *in|on|from|at* November 13.

I bought this bike *in|on|from|at* a sale.

What is the appropriate situation where the words **in, on, from, and at** should be used?

---

I think something similar has been asked before, but I can't seem to find it in this SE site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go with:

I bought this bike *in* the sporting goods department.

I bought this bike *from* an online store.

I bought this bike *on* November 13.

I bought this bike *at* a sale.

Brief explanation:

There is often a "preferred" preposition for a given context, but there may be acceptable alternatives. A native speaker of the language often finds it quite easy to identify the correct preposition by ear.

The first one, "in" implies a particular subset of some set, for example, a specific location, or a date. "I bought this bike in the sporting goods department", or "I bought this bike in London", are examples of specific locations, but there are others. "I bought this bike in December" specifies a particular subset of time".

For the second, "from" seems most appropriate because you're taking/receiving something *from* the store (after exchanging money for it). Now "at" is probably acceptable, but I would consider it more suitable for a physical (bricks-and-mortar) store, e.g. "I bought this nice bike at the bike store". In some kinds of sale, "at" may even be the preferred preposition, e.g. at an auction. You would commonly say "I bought this beautiful landscape at the art auction held yesterday". "At" could also be used to denote a specific time, as in "I bought my bike at 1:15 PM."   "From" would not be an adequate substitute in that sentence.

As for the third one, "on" is pretty much the only suitable preposition to be used when specifying the date on which something was done.

As for the fourth, the explanation is similar to the auction example I already detailed.

Comment: Can you also explain why, and if there are general rules for the usage of such prepositions? Thanks.

Comment: @MarkGabriel Hope this explanation is satisfactory. :)

Comment: For some reason that I cannot explain, highly restrictive conventions govern the use of prepositions connected with events that occur at a particular time. The problem is not so much the existence of such conventions as the fact that different prepositions must be used for different periods or moments. For example: "I bought this bike **in** December 2013 **on** the 4th (*or* "**on** the 4th **of** December 2013"), **at** 3.30 **in** the afternoon". Or: "I first met her **in** 2007; I remember that it was **on** a Friday". In none of these cases can a different preposition be used.